# SoundCloud API, JSONKit + 64 bit

Tags: ios, soundcloud

Are there plans to release a SoundCloud API that plays nicely with 64-bit? Lack of support for this (due I believe to the JSONKit dependency and the use of the now-deprecated isa pointer) is preventing us from working with the API. We've also tried building exclusively for 32-bit, but still see issues arise specifically with JSONKit. Does anyone know if their team is working on an update?

If not, any suggestions on how to get past the JSONKit / deprecated isa pointer issue until an update is realeased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fork on GitHub that contains fixes for the isa-pointer problems in JSONKit, you can find it here: https://github.com/heroims/JSONKit.

However, as multiple sources recommend (see for example this thread: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/133) Apple's `NSJSONSerialization` is a very good alternative. It seems that for iOS 6 and up it is actually faster than JSONKit.